# Quicksort, para matriz bidimensional

Tags: c#, ordenamiento, quicksort

Que tal estoy realizando un programa en el cual necesito aplicar Quicksort, ahora trabajo con una matriz bidimensional, lo que quiero lograr es que cuando se comparen 2 números iguales (`matriz[i,j] <= matriz[i+1,j]`) se compare el valor `[i,j+1]` y el valor `[i+1,j+1]` y decidir cual debe ir primero.
Si alguien tiene alguna idea de como lograr esto se los agradecería, anexo el método quicksort que estoy usando.

```
private void quicksortMenorPeso(int[,] vector, Int64 primero, Int64 ultimo)
    {
        Int64 i, j, central;
        double pivote;
        central = (primero + ultimo) / 2;
        pivote = vector[central, 1];
        i = primero;
        j = ultimo;
        do
        {
            while (vector[i, 1] < pivote) i++;
            while (vector[j, 1] > pivote) j--;
            if (i <= j)
            {
                int temp; int temp2;
                temp = vector[i, 0];
                temp2 = vector[i, 1];
                vector[i, 0] = vector[j, 0];
                vector[i, 1] = vector[j, 1];
                vector[j, 0] = temp;
                vector[j, 1] = temp2;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        } while (i <= j);

        if (primero < j)
        {
            quicksortMenorPeso(vector, primero, j);
        }
        if (i < ultimo)
        {
            quicksortMenorPeso(vector, i, ultimo);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola @Fontz, tengo un par de dudas, ¿quieres ordenar toda la matriz o quieres ordenar una única fila de ésta pero teniendo en cuenta los valores del resto de filas en la ordenación? ¿a la hora pivotar dos elementos de una fila, deseas que se pivoten los elementos de las dos columnas de igual forma? ¿Deseas ordenar solo por filas o quieres que se ordene también por columnas?